# How to properly configure Kerberos principal name

Tags: ibm-mq, ibm-jdk

this is my `krb5.ini` file.

```
    [libdefaults]
        default_realm = TEST.EXAMPLE.COM
        .....
    [realms]
        TEST.EXAMPLE.COM = {
            kdc = test.example.com:88
            master_kdc = test.example.com:88
            default_domain = example.com
        }
    [domain_realm]
    .example.com = EXAMPLE.COM
    example.com = EXAMPLE.COM
```

I created a user `USERA` on the domain, created a credential using `kinit` and have my jaas.config file defined as

```
    example_config {
    com.ibm.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule required
        useDefaultCcache=false
        principal="userA@TEST.EXAMPLE.COM"  
        useCcache="file:///c:/Users/userA/krb5cc_userA"
        debug=true;
    };
```

everything seems ok as it gets authenticated.

```
    [JGSS_DBG_CRED] Retrieving Kerberos creds from cache for principal=userA@TEST.EXAMPLE.COM
    [JGSS_DBG_CRED] Non-interactive login; no callbacks necessary.
    [JGSS_DBG_CRED] Done retrieving Kerberos creds from cache
    [JGSS_DBG_CRED] Login successful
    [JGSS_DBG_CRED] userA@TEST.EXAMPLE.COM added to Subject
    [JGSS_DBG_CRED] Kerberos ticket for userA@TEST.EXAMPLE.COM added to Subject
    [JGSS_DBG_CRED] No keys to add to Subject for userA@TEST.EXAMPLE.COM
```

however now, I am trying to use a service principal name , instead of user principal. I used `ktpass` to create a keytab file

`ktpass -out "c:\mytab.keytab" -princ "Installation1/test.example.com@TEST.EXAMPLE.COM" -mapUser "TEST\userA" -mapOp set -pass password -crypto DES-CBC-MD5 -pType KRB5_NT_PRINCIPAL +DesOnly`

and then use `setspn` to check

```
  C:\>setspn -l userA
Registered ServicePrincipalNames for CN=userA,CN=Users,DC=test,DC=example,DC=com:
   Installation1/test.example.com
```

i change my config to

```
    example_config{
      com.ibm.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule required
                credsType = both                
               principal="userA/test.example.com"
               useDefaultCcache = true     
               useDefaultKeytab = false
                useKeytab = "file:///c:/mytab.keytab"
                debug=true;   
    };
```

now when i run my app, it gives

```
    [JGSS_DBG_CRED] Retrieving Kerberos creds from keytab for principal=Installation1/test.example.com
    [JGSS_DBG_CRED] Service name=Installation1/test.example.com@TEST.EXAMPLE.COM
    [JGSS_DBG_CRED] Check for Default keytab : 
    [JGSS_DBG_CRED] No Kerberos creds in keytab for principal Installation1/test.example.com
    [JGSS_DBG_CRED] No service key in keytab; login failed
```

What did i do wrong in the config file? or is there something i miss in the `ktpass` command? `Installation1` is the service name (of Websphere MQ) when I go to check Control Panel -> Services.  I want to autheticate userA to use Websphere MQ service. (like if i want to let user use HTTP I would put principal as `HTTP/.....TEST.EXAMPLE.COM`

thanks

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing in MQ that performs authentication.  MQ only performs authorization (permission lookup) via its OAM module.

For a default install of MQ (on any platform including z/OS), there is no effective security in MQ.  You can configure MQ to use MQ SSL between a client application and the queue manager (or between 2 queue managers).

The other choice is to purchase a 3rd party MQ security solution like MQAUSX which handles authentication to various targets.